# ndb datastore query fetch_page always returns no cursor and more = false

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, ndb

I have a class which is an ndb.Model.
I am trying to add pagination so I added this:

```
@classmethod
def get_next_page(cls, cursor):
    q = cls.query()
    q_forward = q.order(cls.title)
    if cursor:
        cursor = ndb.datastore_query.Cursor(cursor)
    objects, cursor, more = q_forward.fetch_page(10, start_cursor=cursor)
    return objects, cursor.urlsafe(), more
```

However, fetch_page ALWAYS returns more == false and cursor is always just empty. But if I instead of cursor use offset=5 or offset=10 or whatever it works just fine. The cursor does not update so it always starts from the first item.

I am testing this locally with stub context.

I wonder what am I missing? I'm very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe it should be `ndb._datastore_query.Cursor` (see [reference](https://github.com/googleapis/python-ndb/blob/main/google/cloud/ndb/__init__.py#L38)) or just do `ndb.Cursor`
2. If the cursor came from UI and you had previously made it `urlsafe`, then you should be doing `ndb._datastore_query.Cursor(urlsafe=cursor)` or `ndb.Cursor(urlsafe=cursor)`
3. Also, when you don't have a cursor, make sure it's explicitly set to `None` or just do `ndb.Cursor()` or `ndb._datastore_query.Cursor()`